# Mysqldump error in Aws EC2 Instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, mysql

Instance details: Aws Linux instance

My database contain 1680 individual tables I'm trying to export database in phpmyadmin it failed and i'm trying below command to export db file at end of execution only partial db file created

```
mysqldump -u root -p password exampledb > /var/www/html/exampledb.sql
```

Comment: add the error you are getting

Comment: no error displayed in putty @sri-u please suggest way to check error log

Comment: the mysql version is also important here.  5.7 has some weird issues with certain views... they basically can't  be backed up.  

also push comes to shove keep binlogs as a backup... or a slave.  OR use --force on the dump query ( you WILL need to verify those backups work in jenkins or something )

Comment: i'm using mysql version 5.5 @MattJoyce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally gzip compression helps me to take full database dump without any error.

```
mysqldump -u user -p exampledb |gzip> /var/www/html/exampledb.sql.gz
```